# What's the most efficient way to accumulate dataframes in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe (or could be any RDD) containing several millions row in a well-known schema like this:

```
Key | FeatureA | FeatureB
--------------------------
U1  |        0 |         1
U2  |        1 |         1
```

I need to load a dozen other datasets from disk that contains different features for the same number of keys.  Some datasets are up to a dozen or so columns wide. Imagine:

```
Key | FeatureC | FeatureD |  FeatureE
-------------------------------------
U1  |        0 |        0 |         1

Key | FeatureF
--------------
U2  |        1
```

It feels like a fold or an accumulation where I just want to iterate all the datasets and get back something like this:

```
Key | FeatureA | FeatureB | FeatureC | FeatureD | FeatureE | FeatureF 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
U1  |        0 |        1 |        0 |        0 |        1 |        0
U2  |        1 |        1 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        1
```

I've tried loading each dataframe then joining but that takes forever once I get past a handful of datasets.  Am I missing a common pattern or efficient way of accomplishing this task?

Comment: As some background info, I've tried ordering the dataframes by key hoping to take advantage of some partitioning but haven't seen a large change in execution time.

Comment: I've also resorted to just treating data like strings and reducing by key and concatenating the values, which actually works fairly well.

Comment: @zero323 AFAIK there's no way to explicitly partition a dataframe, aside from the orderBy which supposedly is used in the logical plan (which I did try). If I converted it to a RDD then I might be able to aggregateByKey?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103342/discussion-between-zero323-and-joshua-ewer).

Comment: why do not you use "merge" function that introduce by Spark?

Comment: @HosseinVatani Could you elaborate?

Comment: I meant,[schema-merging](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#schema-merging)

Comment: @HosseinVatani that function is relevant for parquet files but I'm working with CSV data at the moment.  However the concept makes sense and is very similar to the answer zero323 posted.  (Coincidentally, my final output for this larger dataset will be Avro Parquet so the next person down the line won't have to deal with this mess.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there is at most one row per key in each `DataFrame` and all keys are of primitive types you can try an union with an aggregation. Lets start with some imports and example data:

```
from itertools import chain
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit, max
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

df1 = sc.parallelize([
    ("U1", 0, 1), ("U2", 1, 1)
]).toDF(["Key", "FeatureA", "FeatureB"])

df2 = sc.parallelize([
  ("U1", 0, 0, 1)
]).toDF(["Key", "FeatureC", "FeatureD", "FeatureE"])

df3 = sc.parallelize([("U2", 1)]).toDF(["Key", "FeatureF"])

dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
```

Next we can extract common schema:

```
output_schema = StructType(
  [df1.schema.fields[0]] + list(chain(*[df.schema.fields[1:] for df in dfs]))
)
```

and transform all `DataFrames`:

```
transformed_dfs = [df.select(*[
  lit(None).cast(c.dataType).alias(c.name) if c.name not in df.columns 
  else col(c.name)
  for c in output_schema.fields
]) for df in dfs]
```

Finally an union and dummy aggregation:

```
combined = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, transformed_dfs)
exprs = [max(c).alias(c) for c in combined.columns[1:]]
result = combined.repartition(col("Key")).groupBy(col("Key")).agg(*exprs)
```

If there is more than one row per key but individual columns are still atomic you can try to replace `max` with `collect_list` / `collect_set` followed by `explode`.

Comment: spectacular.  working on this approach now and will report back today with questions/comments/whatevers.